# Delay in opening stream in opencv 3.4.1

Tags: vlc, opencv3.0, rtsp

Hello I am trying to capture stream with open cv with python. I am getting a delay of 6 seconds for opening the stream which i feel is very high. In the vlc im able to open the stream in 0.5 seconds at most. Is there any way to fast up the processing of opening the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the opencv Compiled with gstreamer and by making opencv to take default as gstreamer(with cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER) instead of ffmpeg to open the rtsp stream. With this i was able to open the stream in 1.5 seconds